# Pass in a userId parameter when connecting to socket (nodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

so i have a server which users will connect to when they go on my webpage. Im using node js and socket io and when a new players joins, i give them a unique ID. I do this by the code below:

js on html:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" 
src="http://localhost:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

server = io.connect('http://localhost:8081/game');
```

It then connects to my server with the code below:

```
Server.prototype.startSockets = function()
{
    this.socket = io.listen(this.server);

    this.socket.of('game').on('connection', function(user)
        {
            user.userId = this.userId;
            user.userName = this.userName + " " + this.userId;

            this.userId++;

            consoleLog('SERVER', user.userName + ' has connected. ID: ' + user.userId)

            user.emit('response', 
            {
                userId: user.userId,
                userName: user.userName
            });

            user.on('disconnect', function()
                {           
                    this.em.emit('cancelHostGame', user.userId, user.userName);
                    consoleLog('SERVER', user.userName + ' has disconnected. ID: ' + user.userId)
                }
                .bind(this));
        }
        .bind(this));
};
```

It will give the user an ID and then send it back to the client:

```
server.on('connected', function(response)
{
    userId = response.userId;
    userName = response.userName;
});
```

What im trying to do is connect someone with a specific id. So when someone connects, they get an id of 560, save it in a session, i open a new page, read the session id and then connect them with that id.

I tried passing in an id on the client where i do io.connect('localhost...', 560) but i couldnt get that to work. Any help is appriciated

Comment: This looks like there's only one `this.userId` on the server so you'd be assigning the same one to every user that connects.  Why?  Where is your code that creates a unique user id for each connecting user?

Comment: yes userId is set to 1 by default but just after the user connects and is assigned that id, you can see i put this.userId++. So the next user will get an id of 2 and so on.

Comment: If you want a persistent userID for a given browser each time it connects, then you have to put some sort of id into a cookie, either a session cookie and you store the id in the session or put the id itself into the cookie.

Comment: ah yes i was only thinking of php sessions, i forgot node js had a cookie module.So before i assign them a user id i can run a function to check if there is one saved in a cookie and if there is,assign the one they have saved, if not, assign them the this.userId. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be the general idea.

Comment: Also is it possible for users to edit their cookies? it would be very bad if a user could go into chrome cookies and change their id to that of another user

Comment: That is a valid concern.  The more secure way to do it is to put an encrypted session ID in the cookie and store the actual userID in the server-side only session object.  The express-session module is often used for the session cookie and store and session object mangement.

Comment: thanks ill look into that :)